# OAuth 2.0 access_token. Different length

Tags: google-oauth

By OAuth 2.0 I get access_token. It looks like this:

```
ya29.bwCJveFDYXfC3kgAAABve9zwbileOMAamTtH9xsW3ynfjCcJVj7Os33VBGp4VPRLSAdOakOb8we_ws8RtKBjgONmmg3yHt7pA7YRAr1xStkeFQ4XJpe0EooK5G9Syw
```

But in every example from [documentation](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) it looks like different:

```
1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg
```

My question: Why? It does not matter? Or they are different tokens?

Comment: no difference may be that they where smaller at one time.  +1 for actually reading the documentation :)